# Is it possible to shutdown/restart containers with excessive CPU usage with Docker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-swarm, amazon-ecs

For example, if any of the containers is stuck for any reason at 100% CPU for extended period of time (say one minute), is it possible to set up a rule to either shut it down and bring up a new container, or restart it with Docker Swarm or AWS ECS?

Answer (score 1):

I'll bite this because I had a very similar problem on AWS with docker.

First of all, I think you can limit the CPU share, but not the time it uses that share.

Now, I had instances where my app was consuming 100% CPU and couldn't figure out why. Turns out I was using T2 instances, and they have a baseline to which they will drop once you use all cpu credits. So, if you are using say a 1Gb instance, it will drop to 10% baseline. That's like running your apps on a 250Mhz cpu. From inside, the instance will show 100% CPU, but it's actually being limited by the host at a fraction of the real cpu.

If that is your case, you can either increase the instance to earn more credits per time or enable T2 Unlimited, which in most cases that will work without charges, as you have an entire day to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something similar to what you want in AWS like that:
- Create a CloudWatch alarm targeting the `CPUUtilization` metric of your ECS service. See [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_AlarmAtThresholdEC2.html) for an example that uses an EC2 CPU metric.
- As target action select a lambda function you can create that kills all the tasks in the service an spawns new ones, restarting them.

However this is perhaps an overkill. The easiest and official solution to solve the availability problem in ECS is to attach the service to a load balancer and configure a healthcheck endpoint. This way, any containers that fails to respond to the healtcheck call in the specified time will be considered unhealthly and killed, spawning new ones. See [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html) about ECS and load balancing.